# navigationController pushViewController from UIPageViewController not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I am new to iOS development.
I have story board with a Navigation Controller and `UIViewController` connect to it.

In `UIViewController` custom class I add three `UIViewController` under `UIPageViewController`:

```
_one= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View1"];
_two = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View2"];
_three = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View3"];   
_page = [[CustomUIPageViewController alloc] initWithParentViewController:self];
_page.viewControllers = @[_one, _two, _three];
[self.view addSubview:_page.view];
...
```

I want to show a view from page _two by call this code:

```
ResultViewController *view = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ResultBoard"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
```

But it not work, I also try:

```
[self.parentViewController.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
```

Comment: which view is showing?

Comment: @S.Jain It is a storyboard page with UIViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can solve my problem now. It is not a "clean" way but it work.
On the _two Controller I add:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationCustomController;
```

And then when init I add:

```
_two.navigationCustomController = self.navigationController;
```

After that I just call:

```
ResultViewController *view = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ResultBoard"];
[_navigationCustomController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
```

And it work.